# Plot using ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have this plot which I Loaded here. I'm interested in marking the anomalies / those points that are far (I will choose how far)  from the zero line. In the x axis I want that only the anomalies will be written in the x-axis.

This is my code:

```
x_4  <- seq(1000,9999,1)
y1_4 <- comparison4[,1]
y2_4 <- comparison4[,2]
y3_4 <- comparison4[,3]
df <- data.frame(x_4,y4_4,y4_4,y4_4)
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x_4)) +                   
  geom_line(aes(y=y1_4), colour="red") +  
  geom_line(aes(y=y2_4), colour="green")+ 
  geom_line(aes(y=y3_4), colour="blue") + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(1000,2000,3000,4000,5000,6000,7000,8000,9000,9999)) + 
  geom_point(aes(y=y1_4),shape=8, colour="red",size=0.01)+
  geom_point(aes(y=y2_4),shape=6, colour="green",size=0.01)+
  geom_point(aes(y=y3_4),shape = 4, colour="blue",size=4)+
  xlab("Digit") +
  ylab("Frequency") +
  ggtitle("Four Digits Benford Distribution")
```

Comment: your code does not run.

Comment: I think you need to provide `comparison4`?

Comment: Maybe you should give your question a more specific title.

Answer (score 0):

You can subset the data before plotting according to a threshold value. Here with sample data:

```
# sample data
df <- data.frame(x_4 = seq(1000,9999,1),
                 y1_4 = rnorm(9000),
                 y2_4 = rnorm(9000),
                 y3_4 = rnorm(9000))

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

## Set a threshold value
threshold <- 2

## Turn data to long form and keep only those above 0 +- threshold
dft <- gather(data = df,key,value,-x_4) %>%
  filter(value > threshold | value < -threshold)

require(ggplot2)

ggplot(dft, aes(x=x_4,y=value,colour=key,shape=key)) +                   
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(1000,2000,3000,4000,5000,6000,7000,8000,9000,9999)) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red","green","blue")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(8,6,4)) +
  xlab("Digit") +
  ylab("Frequency") +
  ggtitle("Four Digits Benford Distribution")
```

[image]